# Why is the assembly for this Haskell program fairly big w.r.t. equivalent C code? Or what am I doing wrong when compiling?

Tags: c, haskell, assembly, gcc, ghc

Once I asked [Why is Haskell binary for simple "times 2" program so big (wrt e.g. C++)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72155419/why-is-haskell-binary-for-simple-times-2-program-so-big-wrt-e-g-c), but that was duped to [Small Haskell program compiled with GHC into huge binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115459/small-haskell-program-compiled-with-ghc-into-huge-binary).

I've decided to ask a similar question, but with the focus on what the code actually does, so on the assembly form of it, not the binary. [I haven't found an existing answer to my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haskell+assembly).

So no, [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115459/small-haskell-program-compiled-with-ghc-into-huge-binary) doesn't answer my question.

Here's the C++ (well, really C) dumb program that assumes 1 command line argument is given that represents a number, turns it into an `int` and `return`s it multiplied by 2 as the exit code of the executable (yeah, I can't go above 255)

```cpp
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    int r{0};
    int c{0};
    while (argv[1][c] != '\0') {
        r *= 10;
        r += argv[1][c++] - '0';
    }
    return r*2;
}
```

[The assembly is very short (21 lines all inclusive)](https://godbolt.org/z/jW9z5oYc1):

```
main:                                   # @main
        mov     rcx, qword ptr [rsi + 8]
        movzx   edx, byte ptr [rcx]
        test    dl, dl
        je      .LBB0_1
        inc     rcx
        xor     eax, eax
.LBB0_3:                                # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
        movsx   edx, dl
        lea     eax, [rax + 4*rax]
        lea     eax, [rdx + 2*rax]
        add     eax, -48
        movzx   edx, byte ptr [rcx]
        inc     rcx
        test    dl, dl
        jne     .LBB0_3
        add     eax, eax
        ret
.LBB0_1:
        xor     eax, eax
        ret
```

Here's a "similar" Haskell program which accomplishes precisely the same task as far as I can tell, [but which nonetheless generates a much larger assembly (257 lines, so more than 12 times longer](https://godbolt.org/z/obY9KMEze)¹:

```hs
import Data.List (foldl')
import System.Environment (getArgs)
import System.Exit (exitWith, ExitCode (ExitFailure))
main :: IO Int
main = do
  [str] <- getArgs
  exitWith $ ExitFailure $ (*) 2 $ foldl' step 0 str
  where
    step i c = 10 * i + fromEnum c - fromEnum '0'
```

Yes, it does so in a different way, especially because I can't really spit out procedurale code with Haskell, but my point is that the compiler, when I compile the code above, should know that that's the `main` and that none of the intermediate results that could be created for the purpose of computing the exit value are not needed anywhere else. Why can't it work out that all this code is doing can be accomplished with just a few lines of assembly (as demonstreated by the C/C++ program above?)

Or, if that's not the case, then just why is the assembly so big? Am I just forgetting the appropriate compiler flags? Or what?

Is it just that the effort in developing GHC has not been put into optimizing such a small code? (In this case, I would then wonder why,  considering that componentization means dividing a big program in smaller and smaller programs: how can I have an optimal program if I don't optimize its small parts?) Or is optimizing such a small program simply not possible for a fundamental reason I still don't get?

Another thought that comes to mind: maybe *the way I've written the code* is not really prone to be optimized? Maybe if I write it in another form the compiler can do a better job?

As regards the optimization being a hard problem, yes, I believe it, and I know nothing of it. But I thought that the more guarantees the compiler is given, the more it can optimize. And in this respect I thought that Haskell is better.

---

Surely I could spend some time to write the Haskell code which expressed precisely the same process I expressed in C. But given the size of the assembly I have at the moment... will it really do a big difference?

Please, if you think that's the case, tell me, and I'll delete this question and take time to try that.

---

Some comments refer to things like

- It contains a runtime environment to determine what thunks to evaluate, etc.
- It will not grow up tu significsantly later as haskel needs plenty libraries and startup code

But just why? I mean,

- What the program does is simple. Is it really so difficult for the compiler to work it out? Why would the thunks be even needed, if the program boils down to such a simple operation?
- It seems so "wrong" to me that one has to reach a critical mass of code.

As a comparison, I was astonished when I read (and verified) that Clang works out that this C code

```cpp
int foo(int a) {
    int count = 0;
    while (a) {
        ++count;
        a &= a - 1;
    }
    return count;
}
```

boils down to a set bit count, hence it compiles it down to just

```
foo(int):                                # @foo(int)
        popcntl %edi, %eax
        retq
```

if the architecture has got `popcntl`.

---

(¹) It turns out that [@Cubic's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77069540/why-is-the-assembly-for-this-haskell-program-fairly-big-w-r-t-equivalent-c-code?noredirect=1#comment135866149_77069540) gives a way to get [a slightly shorter assembly](https://godbolt.org/z/9hzEEn77K) (182 lines, so still almost 9 times longer than the C program above) by removing the assumption that there's only one command line argument, by changing this

```hs
  [str] <- getArgs
  exitWith $ ExitFailure $ (*) 2 $ foldl' step 0 str
```

to this,

```hs
  str <- getArgs
  exitWith $ ExitFailure $ (*) 2 $ foldl' step 0 $ head str
```

As regards the other point @Cubic makes, i.e. that the Haskell program *needs to iterate through a (lazy) linked list to parse the string*, I don't think that can be removed. Removing it, even if it is (is it?) possible, would in my opinion mean that we are giving up on the nature of Haskell, giving up on the idiomatic way of doing things and embracing the emulation of another language which has nothing to do with Haskell.

Comment: It contains a runtime environment to determine what thunks to evaluate, etc.

Comment: It will not grow up tu significsantly later as haskel needs plenty libraries and startup code

Comment: @cafce25, no it doesn't. I'm not referring to the size of the binary, but to the amount of instructions in the assembly.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, the two programs have the same observable behavior (to my knowledge; or they don't?), so the shorter code is the better, no? Or, in other words, is any of the things you refer to really necessary for the task?

Comment: The size of the binary directly correlates with the number of instructions in the assembly of the binary...

Comment: @cafce25, yes, I does, but I'm not interested in why the binary is large. I'm interested in why the compiler can't produce just enough assembly as it's needed to accomlish the task. Then yes, if it was able to, it would have generated a smaller binary, but as you say, that's a consequence.

Comment: Theoretically it's possible but optimization is a hard problem...

Comment: @Enlico: the runtime environment is something that always ships with the executable, but is not per see used (completely). So one can not really determine how that affects performance, just like an embedded file does not change much of the performance of a program. For example in a lot of cases lazy evaluation (which is one of the reasons why thunks are used), can avoid a lot of computational effort.

Comment: The program itself is however not very efficient, since it works with `reverse` and then a `map` with `(10 ^)`, here a folding pattern is more advisable.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, fair enough, but still. Is there no analysis that can determine what parts of the environment are used and what not? I get your point about performance, but that's a bit similar to cafce25's point about the binary. I see the correlation, but that's not my point. Even if many instructions don't affect the performance, I still wonder "why are they there?"

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, yeah, I referred to the non-optimality of the Haskell program. I can try to rewrite it using a fold to see if the assembly gets smaller

Comment: @Enlico: no, or only marginally, since it thus starts with a huge offset, but the size of a binary is just strange as a performance metric. A `for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {}` will be a lot shorter than 50 times `i++`, but that does not mean the it is less efficient. Aggressively determining what base libraries and runtime environments are (not) used will only pay off for rather small programs, but this is often not the intended use-case, just like the operating system is something that is also attached to programs, and often not used completely, but not a problem w.r.t. performance.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, I guess you mean _that does not mean that it (the for loop) is more efficient_? (Incidentally, I've updated the Haskell program to use `foldl'`, if that's close to what you alluded to.)

Comment: @cafce25: The OP is asking about the assembly instructions generated directly from this source, as shown in the Godbolt link in their question (https://godbolt.org/z/obY9KMEze).  That's not disassembly of the binary, that's *just* the compiler's actual output, which can get assembled and *then* linked into a huge binary.  This is not a duplicate of [Small Haskell program compiled with GHC into huge binary](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6115459).  The actual compiler-generated asm isn't HUGE, just large for the amount of source if you're used to lower-level languages, about 150 to 200 asm insns.

Comment: @PeterCordes, in a previous edit of the question I had a more convoluted and dumber Haskell implementation, which resulted in an even longer assembly, hence I wrote "HUGE". I should probably edit the title.

Comment: Your C program is superficially doing something similar to the Haskell program, but there’s a lot more going on in the Haskell program which ends up in the final executable. 2 big differences are that the Haskell program is checking that exactly 1 command line argument is passed and it needs to iterate through a (lazy) linked list to parse the string. That just involves a lot more instructions than iterating through a strict byte buffer like in your C example (but yes, this is not a duplicate of the big binary question).

Comment: You could just as easily ask why something like Python or Bash doesn't produce a tight assembler loop for an equivalent example; their language implementations *could* statically analyze code this small (even if it's not possible in general) and emit tight machine code. But that would be a large effort that wouldn't scale to the rest of the language implementation. Instead they execute small examples with algorithms designed to apply generally to any program, large or small.

Comment: C as a language was designed to map pretty straightforwardly to machine-level operations. So unsurprisingly, a small simple C program produces a small amount of assembly. That was simply never a design goal of Haskell. And especially the basic interface to stdin/stout and command line args are represented with high level data structures in Haskell and with direct byte and system call access in C. So any very small whole-program like this is going to have that extra work in Haskell; it's a pretty big ask to perfectly compile it away. But in realistic code that's a tiny fraction of the program.

Comment: @Ben, even compiling just the pure functions that process the string ([`String -> Int` in Haskell](https://godbolt.org/z/8ne8rfh4b) vs [`int(char const *)` in C](https://godbolt.org/z/v6rTK966d)), which are free from having to interface with stdin/stdout/cli, generate a fairly different amount of assembly.

Comment: @Enlico `String` is a relatively high level data structure (a linked list of objects containing individual characters). `char *` is just a raw pointer to a chunk of bytes (without even length information!). It's not that interfacing with stdin/stdout/etc has extra cost "just because", but that in Haskell those interfaces are exposed in terms of high level data structures (like `String`), so you have to use high level operations to process them. In C you're doing pointer arithmetic; almost working in assembly language concepts already.

Answer (score 11):

The C++ compiler isn't writing this highly optimized code. You are.

If you start using some of the same kinds of libraries in C++ as you do in Haskell, you'll find that it no longer generates neat and short assembly:

```cpp
#include <gmpxx.h>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  mpz_class r{0};
  mpz_class c{0};
  for(char c : std::string(argv[1])) {
    r *= 10;
    r += c - '0';
  }
  r *= 2;
  return r.get_ui();
}
```

Meanwhile, if you start writing Haskell the same way you write C++ (which is really not my forte but this was my first attempt):

```
foo :: Ptr CChar -> Int
foo !ptr = unsafePerformIO $ do
    n <- f 0 ptr
    return $! n*2
  where
    f :: Int -> Ptr CChar -> IO Int
    f !n !ptr = do
        c <- peek ptr
        if c == 0 then return n else f (n*10+(fromEnum c - 0x30)) (plusPtr ptr 1)
```

Then you'll find that GHC also produces much tighter code:

```
  406c48:  add    r12,0x10
  406c4c:  cmp    r12,QWORD PTR [r13+0x358]
  406c53:  ja     406c8a <Main_zdwf_info+0x42>
  406c55:  movsx  rax,BYTE PTR [rsi]              # c = *s
  406c59:  test   rax,rax                         # if c == 0
  406c5c:  je     406c75 <Main_zdwf_info+0x2d>      
  406c5e:  add    r12,0xfffffffffffffff0
  406c62:  inc    rsi                             # s++
  406c65:  imul   r14,r14,0xa                     # r *= 10
  406c69:  add    r14,rax                         # r += c
  406c6c:  lea    rax,[r14-0x30]                  # tmp = r - '0'
  406c70:  mov    r14,rax                         # r = tmp
  406c73:  jmp    406c48 <Main_zdwf_info>
```

Comment: Interesting answer! A couple tweaks: `mpz_class c{0};` is shadowed by `char c` declared inside the range-`for`.  Regardless, `c-'0'` has to get promoted to a type compatible with `mpz_class r` for the `+=` operation.  (Also, you probably want `unsigned char c`; sign-extending elements from a `std::string` is usually not what you want; it makes the result potentially weirder if you run it on non-ASCII characters.  In the x86-64 System V ABI, `char` is a signed type, unlike the standard ABIs on ARM for example.  Or maybe you don't; your GHC output is using a `movsx` sign-extending byte load.)

Comment: It should produce essentially the same code for `foo :: Ptr CChar -> IO Int` with no `unsafePerformIO`. I recommend this, as `foo` is in fact not referentially transparent -- passing the same pointer multiple times can result in different ints if the data behind the pointer is modified between calls.

Comment: How do I make a complete example out of this, so that I can compare it to the C case? (I mean, with a `main` entry point and that I can compile, link, and call from command line?)

Comment: @Enlico You can invoke it with `main = do { [arg] <- getArgs; s <- newCString arg; print $ foo s; }`. The binary will still be huge and isolating your actual code for comparison may be difficult. There may be a way to simplify the process but I'm not aware of it.

Comment: @thatotherguy, but your solution (+ appropriate `import`s and the `main`) gives an assembly which is [slightly longer](https://godbolt.org/z/8W99vf8c5) than [the one I proposed](https://godbolt.org/z/obY9KMEze). And if I isolate your solution into a module that exports only that, and I do the same for mine, [yours](https://godbolt.org/z/znoev8bjo) still generates more assembly than [mine](https://godbolt.org/z/e5Pcf7zb9). This is to say that I think the comparison you've set up with this answer is not really fair, as my question is about a complete program in C vs one equivalent in Haskell.

Comment: @Enlico Godbolt only shows the size of the main method. It does not show the size of the binary or runtime. The business logic in my example is ~7 independent instructions, while yours is at least 30 with two calls into the runtime. I'm assuming it's not your intention to assign an `inc` instruction and the GHC runtime roughly the same weight for counting code size.